# $_GET only picks up 'ID'

Tags: php, string, iframe, get

i have a very strange issue, or maybe im overlooking something really simple.

i have a URL : http://sub.domain.com.au/q/quote-step-two/?id=228&optionid=278

and i cant get 'optionid' in php.

so to test this out i tried:

```
echo "\$optid =". $optid ; // empty
echo "get =" . $_GET['optionid']; // empty 
var_dump($_GET); //array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "228" }
```

strange thig is, if i change the url to :

sub.domain.com.au/q/quote-step-two/?optionid=278

or even

sub.domain.com.au/q/quote-step-two/

`var_dump($_GET)` gives me `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" }`

if i look up the url on httpfox it shows the 2 get variables.

this is the htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

at the moment this works if i q/quote-step-two/228. how do i get it to pick up a 2nd param? like q/quote-step-two/228/227/

Comment: what happens for parameters other than `optionid`, say `foo`?

Comment: they dont come up either, it only picks up ID, even if ID is not on the query string

Comment: I'm somewhat certain (5¢ bet) that it's a `RewriteRule` causing this.

Comment: im not very good with rewrites and i didnt write this either. the only thing i could find is this

the .htaccess is part of drupal cms. can i change it withouth breaking drupal?
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @heshan: I would have suspected the `[QSA]` is missing. This rule looks okay. But since your `var_dump` printout lacks the `q=` parameter, this might not be the occured RewriteRule. You should try to invoke the complete URL yourself `.../quote-step-two/index.php?optionid=277&foo=test`

Comment: Can you find the string anywhere in $_SERVER? maybe it got appended somewhere else unexpectedly.

Comment: spot on, quote/step-2.php?id=228&optionid=278 gives the proper output. who ever wrote this code in the first place should be killed. its running inside a iframe, which is on a drupal page

Comment: @mario, I don't think it will work because every request is overwritten. @heshan benefits of using popular CMS :)

Comment: @webarto: Seems it worked without disabling the offending rule. So @heshan, you could post the complete .htaccess, maybe we can help search.

Comment: @mario, then probably -f -d is set.

Comment: url on the iframe was only getting the ID of the parent page, so watever i added after that was being ignored

Comment: this is the htaccess

  
  `RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

 at the moment this works if i q/quote-step-two/228. how do i get it to pick up a 2nd param? like q/quote-step-two/228/227/

Comment: @heshan there is internal router written in PHP, you have to look there. Every request that isn't file or folder is forwarded there via q parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$q = $_GET["q"];
unset($_GET["q"]);

$gets = explode("&", $q);

foreach($gets as $get){
    $get = explode("=", $get);
    $_GET[$get[0]] = $get[1];
}

print_r($_GET);
```

Update

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$uri = explode("?", $uri);

if(!empty($uri[1])){
    $gets = explode("&", $uri[1]);
        foreach($gets as $get){
            $get = explode("=", $get);
            $_GET[$get[0]] = $get[1];
        }
}

print_r($_GET);
```

Comment: @heshan This won't work because $q is destroyed before you ran script. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

ok after much hairpulling this was the issue.

even though the parent page had the 2nd param on the query string the iframe url embdded in the page only had id, thats it was showing 'id=' even when the parent url was empty,

i simply copied and added the parent query string to the ifram path. and that fixed the issue